Replicating excel COUNTIFS with multiple criteria from one dataset used on values in another dataset
I have a variant to the "how do I do an Excel COUNTIFS equivalent statement in python?' question.
In my instance, I wish to count how many items appear in a population with a score greater than or equal to a target score.  The target score for a given changes each row.
The first dataset would be the required parameters.

    type    required_score
    A   4
    A   5
    A   6
    A   7
    B   1
    B   3
    B   8
    B   9
    C   2
    C   5
    C   6
    C   7
    C   8


The second dataset would be the population to be assessed vs. those requirements.

    type    actual_score
    A   3
    A   2
    A   7
    A   5
    B   1
    B   3
    B   8
    B   9
    C   8
    C   8
    C   3
    C   2


My aim would be to produce a column ('Available Population') that tells me how many scores in the second table are available that were GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO the required score defined in the first table.   It's the GT/E bit that's got me stumped.

    type    required_score  available_population
    A   4              2
    A   5              2
    A   6              1
    A   7              1
    B   1              4
    B   3              3
    B   8              2
    B   9              1
    C   2              4
    C   5              2
    C   6              2
    C   7              2
    C   8              2


Without constraining any answers, I would prefer pandas based solutions (if only to increase my understanding of how to use this library a bit better!).  I've started to understand various groupby, agg and transform functions.  I know the answer is going to be a combination of some of those methods!

Using df.merge, df.query, df.groupby, and groupby.agg to get size. Adding df.reindex to get back groups with size 0:
cols = ['type', 'required score']

out = (
    df.merge(df2, on='type', how='left')
    .query('`actual score` >= `required score`')
    .groupby(cols)['actual score']
    .agg(**{'available population': 'size'})
    .reindex(df.set_index(cols).index, fill_value=0)
    .reset_index()
)

Output:
   type  required score  available population
0     A               4                     2
1     A               5                     2
2     A               6                     1
3     A               7                     0 # adjusted `df2` to get size 0
4     B               1                     4
5     B               3                     3
6     B               8                     2
7     B               9                     1
8     C               2                     4
9     C               5                     2
10    C               6                     2
11    C               7                     2
12    C               8                     2

Explanation / Intermediates

df.merge(df2, on='type', how='left').head(5)

# get all `actual scores` next to each `required score` option per `type`

  type  required score  actual score
0    A               4             3
1    A               4             2
2    A               4             6
3    A               4             5
4    A               5             3


.query('`actual score` >= `required score`').head(6)

# this filters out rows that fail the condition
# e.g., notice that row 0, 1 are gone
# and group (A, 7) is gone entirely (group size 0)

   type  required score  actual score
2     A               4             6
3     A               4             5
6     A               5             6
7     A               5             5
10    A               6             6
16    B               1             1


With .groupby we collect groups of cols (column labels: ['type', 'required score']) and get the size. By using **{'available population': 'size'} we pass to agg the output name (i.e. our desired column label: 'available population') as key, and the function to be applied (i.e. size) as the value.
Finally, we can use df.reindex and pass df.set_index(cols).index to get back groups with size 0, which will have been filtered out by query, adding fill_value=0.
df.reset_index will get cols back as columns.

Data used
import pandas as pd

data = {'type': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 
                 7: 'B', 8: 'C', 9: 'C', 10: 'C', 11: 'C', 12: 'C'}, 
        'required score': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3, 6: 8, 7: 9, 
                           8: 2, 9: 5, 10: 6, 11: 7, 12: 8}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data2 = {'type': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 
                  7: 'B', 8: 'C', 9: 'C', 10: 'C', 11: 'C'}, 
         'actual score': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 6, 3: 5, 4: 1, 5: 3, 6: 8, 7: 9, 
                          8: 8, 9: 8, 10: 3, 11: 2}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# adjusted `df2.iloc[2]`

# type            A
# actual score    6 
# Name: 2, dtype: object

# from `7` to `6` to create group with size 0

Side note
It is generally a good idea to use underscores (_) instead of whitespaces ( ) for your column labels. E.g., then you don't need the backticks (`) inside query and can pass the NamedAgg inside agg like below:
cols = ['type', 'required_score']

out = (
    df.merge(df2, on='type', how='left')
    .query('actual_score >= required_score')
    .groupby(cols)
    .agg(available_population=('actual_score', 'size'))
    .reindex(df.set_index(cols).index, fill_value=0)
    .reset_index()
)

A bit easier on the eyes as well :).

thank you for this.  it just makes it so much easier.  I was not aware of how to implement the .query() piece.

You're welcome! Added a side note on some of the benefits of using underscores in your column labels. For future ref as well.

I discovered a problem with the proposal. If there are NO instances of the 'actual score' >= 'required score' then you lose the line completely. Ideally I would want the line to have 0 as the answer, not be lost entirely by the query parameters.
To confirm this,  I dropped all actual_scores for A below the minimum required_scores and A disappears from the results entirely. Ideally, A would return 0
To overcome this limitation, two more steps are required:

final = df.merge(out,how='left', on=['type','required_score'], suffixes=('','_z'))
then:
final['available_population'] = final['available_population'].fillna(0).astype(int)

You're right. I've updated the answer. You can get the groups with size 0 back with df.reindex.

that's amazing.
it simply isn't possible to learn this from the docs alone!!!

Updated the explanation as well. Good luck with the project!

had to change to .reset_index(names=cols)  as the columns were getting renamed to level_0, level_1, level_2 etc.

Interesting. You need that as well for the dummy example here? Cos I ran this code (so without names=cols) just now both on pd version 2.2.1 and 1.4.1 and it's working fine for both. What pd version do you run (pd.__version__)?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can achieve this this way:
import pandas as pd

data_required = {
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'required_score': [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}
df_required = pd.DataFrame(data_required)

data_actual = {
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'actual_score': [3, 2, 7, 5, 1, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 3, 2]
}
df_actual = pd.DataFrame(data_actual)

df_merged = pd.merge(df_required, df_actual, on='type')
df_filtered = df_merged[df_merged['actual_score'] >= df_merged['required_score']]
df_result = df_filtered.groupby(['type', 'required_score']).size().reset_index(name='available_population')
df_final = pd.merge(df_required, df_result, on=['type', 'required_score'], how='left')
df_final['available_population'] = df_final['available_population'].fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df_final)

or
import pandas as pd

data_required = {
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'required_score': [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}
df_required = pd.DataFrame(data_required)

data_actual = {
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'actual_score': [3, 2, 7, 5, 1, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 3, 2]
}
df_actual = pd.DataFrame(data_actual)

df_merged = pd.merge(df_required, df_actual, on='type')

available_population = (
    df_merged[df_merged['actual_score'] >= df_merged['required_score']]
    .groupby(['type', 'required_score'])
    .size()
    .reset_index(name='available_population')
)
df_final = pd.merge(df_required, available_population, on=['type', 'required_score'], how='left').fillna(0).astype({'available_population': int})

print(df_final)

which gives you:
   type  required_score  available_population
0     A               4                     2
1     A               5                     2
2     A               6                     1
3     A               7                     1
4     B               1                     4
5     B               3                     3
6     B               8                     2
7     B               9                     1
8     C               2                     4
9     C               5                     2
10    C               6                     2
11    C               7                     2
12    C               8                     2


Thank you.  That works equally well as the 2 prior methods.

You could "construct" the criteria based on each row of your thresholds DataFrame and apply it row wise -
import pandas as pd

data_required = {
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'required_score': [4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 8, 9, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}
df_required = pd.DataFrame(data_required)

data_actual = {
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'actual_score': [3, 2, 7, 5, 1, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 3, 2]
}
df_actual = pd.DataFrame(data_actual)

df_required['greater_than_or_equal'] = df_required.apply(lambda row: df_actual[(df_actual['type'] == row['type']) & (df_actual['actual_score'] >= row['required_score'])].index.size, axis=1)

Output
   type  required_score  greater_than_or_equal
0     A               4                      2
1     A               5                      2
2     A               6                      1
3     A               7                      1
4     B               1                      4
5     B               3                      3
6     B               8                      2
7     B               9                      1
8     C               2                      4
9     C               5                      2
10    C               6                      2
11    C               7                      2
12    C               8                      2


This also works and helped me understand how to stipulate criteria from another dataframe properly.  TVM.
